# What is the probability of her passing the second test given that she has passed the first test?

Tags: probability

Susan took two tests. The probability of her passing both tests is 0.6. The probability of her passing the first test is 0.8. What is the probability of her passing the second test given that she has passed the first test?

Comment: Literally plug into the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ represent passing the first test, and $B$ represent passing the second test:

$$Pr(B \vert A) = \frac{Pr(B \cap A)}{Pr(A)}$$
$$Pr(B \vert A) = \frac{0.6}{0.8}$$
$$Pr(B \vert A) = 0.75$$